# What should be our decision making strategy at each point of time pertaining to goal setting according to Hinduism scriptures?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras

Kindly elaborate on the decision-making strategy we should use every time regardless of whether any problem is there or not according to mainly Bhagavad Gita? How should we take action in small daily life issues while still being a BG follower? Is there any religious scripture on decision-making? Small issues are like for example there is a person X who is studying, but suddenly his friends show him his new phone. Now technically seeing won't take much time but actually, it would be against the spirit of our purpose of life. Reiterating - Kindly explain decision-making strategy, accrd. to any scripture, one can employ at **each point of life including small and minor issues**

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.! You may wanna visit [How does a New User get started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to help you with getting familiar with the site. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: What has a phone got to do with decision making? More so - what's expected of BG here? Decisions are taken as per the individual's maturity and there's no Gold standard for taking decisions. Can you please be more precise?

Comment: I want to apply BG in all aspects of my life. Every decision has its consequences both good and bad. So how can one decide which action to take in a situation? What factors and pointers should be in mind? For instance, we have a priority matrix for time management, so is there any such useful technique for decision making?